# wso2 esb over HTTP console page not finding resources to display the next page

Tags: apache, http, wso2, wso2-esb

We have installed wso2 esb on centos machine and also have enabled HTTP for console.
 We are able to access and login into HTTPS page, whereas we are able to load and login to the console but unable to view the next page. 
 Console is facing issues in finding a few resources.

Comment: Do you mean that you can login but 'management console' page is partially loading?

Comment: Yes, it was not rendering the next page, we resolved it by making changes to the carbon xml.

Comment: OK. You may add your answer. :)